# AngularJS promise handling with http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

here is a piece of code I am struggling with - I have a controller (zmApp.MonitorCtrl) that is calling a factory (ZMFactory) with an HTTP request.

The problem I am facing is this: 
a) When the controller calls ZMFactory.getMonitors() it returns undef and I get an error 
ERROR: Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ZMFactory.getMonitors().then')

b) After this error comes up, the http request in the factory is processed

I am a little confused. Can you please check if the factory has been set up correctly to return a promise?

```html
var app = angular.module('zmApp.controllers');

app.controller('zmApp.MonitorCtrl',  function($ionicPlatform, $scope,$http,ZMFactory)
{
            
            $scope.monitors=[];
            console.log("***CALLING FACTORY");
            ZMFactory.getMonitors().then(function(data)
            {
               $scope.monitors = data;
               console.log ("I GOT " +$scope.monitors);
            });
               
});



app.factory('ZMFactory',['$http', '$rootScope',function($http,$rootScope)
{
    //var factory = {};
    var monitors =[];
    return {
        getMonitors: function()
        {
            console.log("***MAKING REQUEST");
            $http({
                    url:'http://myurl.com:9999/zm/index.php?skin=xml',
                    method:'post',
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                               'Accept': '*/*',
                               },
                        transformRequest: function(obj) {
                               var str = [];
                               for(var p in obj)
                               str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                               var foo= str.join("&");
                               console.log ("****RETURNING "+foo);
                               return foo;
                        },
                        transformResponse: function(data)
                        {
                            var x2js = new X2JS();
                            var json = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
                            console.log ("***Transmogrifying XML to JSON");
                            return json;
                        },
                        data: {username:'xxx',
                               password:'xxxx',
                               action:'login',
                               view:'console'}
                               
                      }) //http
                      .success (function(data)
                      {
                          console.log("****YAY"+JSON.stringify(data));
                                   
                          var subobj =data.ZM_XML.MONITOR_LIST.MONITOR;
                          var len = subobj.length;
                          for (var i =0; i< len; i++)
                          {
                           console.log ("HERE " + subobj[i].NAME);
                           monitors.push(subobj[i]);
                           }
                          // $rootScope.$broadcast ('handleZoneMinderMonitorsUpdate',monitors);
                           return monitors;
                        }) //success
                        .error(function(data, status, headers, config)
                        {
                           console.log("***OOPS "+status + " H: "+data);
                           return monitors;
                        });

        } //getMonitors
    };//return
    console.log ("**** NEVER *****");
                        
}]);
```

Comment: do you need a dependencies array for the controller?

Comment: Hi Plato, I am not sure, but I don't think so -- the factory is callable from the controller.

Comment: ah, i see, yes the getModules function is not returning a promise. sorry i don't know how to construct a promise.

Comment: one way to do it would be to move the success/error handlers out of the getMonitors function; and `return $http({ ...})`; then you could handle `.then(onSuccess, onError)` in the controller. but it is probably better to research and create your own promise wrapping the entire http req/rep

Comment: Plato thanks. Yes that is an option but like you said I want to move the complete processing to the factory as many controllers will be invoking it.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to the answer is in the wording of your own question:

> Can you please check if the factory has been set up correctly to ***return*** a promise

You need to `return` it. Right now your `getMonitors` function (if I remove all the code irrelevant to the question) is as follows:

```
getMonitors: function(){
  $http({})
    .success(function(data){
       // convert data to monitors
       return monitors;
    });
}
```

This is a function call that doesn't return anything, or rather, returns `undefined`. There is no "magic" with promises - it's just as any other object - you need to return it to the caller.

So, two things you need to do:

1) Change from `.success` to `.then`. `.then` generates a new chained promise that delivers, when returned, the `monitors` to the consumer (that you are returning in the `.then` handler). On the other hand, `.success` returns the original promise (generated by `$http`) and data returning from `.success` is lost.

2) Actually `return` the `$http` call (or, rather, `$http().then()` call)

Here's conceptually how this would look like:

```
app.factory('ZMService', function ZMServiceFactory($http){
    return {
        // getMonitors function of the ZMService service
        getMonitors: function(){
          return $http({})
            .then(function(response){
               var data = response.data;
               // convert data to monitors
               return monitors;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

(also, noticed how I renamed your service from `ZMFactory` to `ZMService`. A "factory" in the name is a misnomer. The factory is the function that generates the instance - hence "the factory" - but the instance itself is an object, which is called a "service" in Angular)

Comment: thanks. My original code above did have a return right above getMonitors in the factory. Is that not equivalent? Also in your code, can you please see if there should be a { after return? I'm trying your suggestion and am getting other issues which I'll outline, once I hear back on this clarification

Comment: @user1361529, I think the `return` that you are referring to is the return value of your factory function - i.e. the instance of your service. And I checked - it doesn't seem like I am missing a `{` - so, not sure what you mean

Comment: New Dev, thanks. I'm going completely bonkers. I think I've refactored to make it the way you recommended. My updated code is here http://pastebin.com/qJtR5b9d

Now I'm getting a ERROR: Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'zmApp.MonitorCtrl' is not a function, got undefined. I bet its some semicolon or parentheses somewhere and I can't figure it out!

Comment: @user1361529, one error right away is that `.then` gets a `response` object - not `data` - see again the difference between `.then` and `.success` in my answer above. Other than that, if the code you posted is the whole code, then you need to do: `var app = angular.module('zmApp.controllers', []);` - notice the `[]` brackets.

Comment: Thanks - that is not why I'm getting an undefined zmApp.MonitorCtrl, however. If I delete the factory function and delete the factory invocation from MonitorCtrl, it works without runtime errors - so I bet its something inside the factory. 

This is not the full code, I'm instantiating zmApp.controllers with parentheses elsewhere 

I'll keep digging

Comment: @user1361529, then it's an unrelated issue. Feel free to post another question if you can't solve it

Comment: @user1361529, you also have some misaligned brackets, but other than that it doesn't fail: http://plnkr.co/edit/H4ZPAloD19NB7EkQO1QT?p=preview

Comment: It works! I don't know what was wrong in mine, but I just cut pasted your code, updated the controller definition and boom it started working. Thank you so much for digging in - you delivered on your promise :-)

Answer (score 1):

try with this,here i am returning the promise as is

```
var app = angular.module('zmApp.controllers');

app.controller('zmApp.MonitorCtrl',  function($ionicPlatform, $scope,$http,ZMFactory)
{

            $scope.monitors=[];
            console.log("***CALLING FACTORY");
            ZMFactory.getMonitors().then(function(data)
            {
               $scope.monitors = data;
               console.log ("I GOT " +$scope.monitors);
            });

});



app.factory('ZMFactory',['$http', '$rootScope',function($http,$rootScope)
{
    //var factory = {};
    var monitors =[];
    return {
        getMonitors: function()
        {

          return  $http({
                    url:'http://myurl.com:9999/zm/index.php?skin=xml',
                    method:'post',
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                               'Accept': '*/*',
                               },
                        transformRequest: function(obj) {
                               var str = [];
                               for(var p in obj)
                               str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                               var foo= str.join("&");
                               console.log ("****RETURNING "+foo);
                               return foo;
                        },
                        transformResponse: function(data)
                        {
                            var x2js = new X2JS();
                            var json = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
                            console.log ("***Transmogrifying XML to JSON");
                            return json;
                        },
                        data: {username:'xxx',
                               password:'xxxx',
                               action:'login',
                               view:'console'}

                      }) //http
                      .then(function(data)
                      {
                          console.log("****YAY"+JSON.stringify(data));

                          var subobj =data.ZM_XML.MONITOR_LIST.MONITOR;
                          var len = subobj.length;
                          for (var i =0; i< len; i++)
                          {
                           console.log ("HERE " + subobj[i].NAME);
                           monitors.push(subobj[i]);
                           }
                          // $rootScope.$broadcast ('handleZoneMinderMonitorsUpdate',monitors);
                           return monitors;
                        },function(error)
                        {

                           return error;
                        });

        }
    };

}]);
```

Comment: Thanks pranay. I wanted to avoid $q as I had read http already returns a promise - I would go this route if I did not get the model right in the previous way, which I managed to get right with the help from New Dev.

Comment: one more thing,i think transform request and response you should keep it in interceptors just to clean up the code